# Activity getting stuck after trying to get all files with same extension

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to get all files on the device with same extension using:

```
private void scanForEpubs() {
    File[] file = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().listFiles();
    for (File ff : file) {
        if (ff.isDirectory()) scanForEpubs(f);
        if (ff.isFile() && ff.getName().endsWith(".epub")) {
            Log.d(TAG, "scanForEpubs: " + ff.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

But that activity gets stuck on a blank screen and doesn't load anything.

Stacktrace gets flooded with just one message:

```
I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 49529(2MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 9% free, 21MB/23MB, paused 10.291ms total 62.505ms
```

Comment: are you running it on background thread ?

Comment: and what is your parameter for scanForEpubs for first method call ?

Comment: @ABDevelopers I'm running it on the UI thread. Parameter is `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`

Comment: I have added my answer check if it helps

Comment: I have updated my answer please check

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing your code a bit :

```
 if (ff.isDirectory()) {
    //here instead of f you should put ff
     scanForEpubs(ff);
 }else{
      if (ff.isFile() && ff.getName().endsWith(".epub")) {
            Log.d(TAG, "scanForEpubs: " + ff.toString());
      }
 }
```

What you were doing was getting into recursive infinite loop.

Comment: Thanks. That worked! I was recursively searching in the same directory.

Answer (score 1):

```
 private static void scanForEpubs(File f) {
        File[] file = f.listFiles();


        for (File ff : file) {
            if (ff.isFile() && ff.getName().endsWith(".pdf")) {
                System.out.println(ff.getName());
            }else {
                if(ff.isDirectory()){
                    scanForEpubs(ff);
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: This doesn't search files in the sub-directories